# Duplicate content and the HREFLang Attribute

Tags: duplicate-content, hreflang

If you have example.com written in British English and then an HREFLang alternate of example.com/en-gb/, so both pages have exactly the same copy in the same language.

With the correct technical set up with the HREFLang including return links and x-default.

Would this run the risk of being seen as duplicated content?

Comment: I would tailor _some_ aspects of the GB version from a UX perspective just to offer a unique experience. As far as duplicate content concerns, you'll be fine. HoldOffHunger presents Google's official guidelines, and I agree with him that your approach looks just fine.

Answer (score 2):

For Google, you will not have any issues, as long as you are using the `hreflang` attribute, as you described.  Source: [Google: Tell Google about localized versions of your page](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/localized-versions).

> Add `<link rel="alternate" hreflang="lang_code"... >` elements to your page header to tell Google all of the language and region variants of a page. This is useful if you don't have a sitemap or the ability to specify HTTP response headers for your site.
>
> Each variation of the page should include a set of  elements in the  element, one link for each page variant including itself. The set of links is identical for every version of the page. See the additional guidelines.
>
> Here is the syntax of each link element:
>
> `<link rel="alternate" hreflang="lang_code" href="url_of_page" />`

The link above provides two other methods, using headers and a sitemap, to accomplish the same objective, but your `hreflang` approach looks good.